# How to display a message on screen without refreshing like SO does?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

The best example of this is through SO. You can be viewing a question, and without refreshing the page you will get an orange message at the top of the screen letting you know you got a badge and check your profile. This all happens without refreshing the page.

I am curious how you go about doing that? I am going to guess something with AJAX. Any direction would be great.