# How to show popup message like in Stack Overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to add a popup message like the one that appears on Stack Overflow when I am not logged in and I try to use voting buttons.

What is the best method for achieving that?
Is it done using a jquery library?

Comment: View the source!

Comment: There is [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604577/how-to-display-a-message-on-screen-without-refreshing-like-so-does) question. You might want to check that as well.

Comment: i did that, and it seemed to refer to question.min.js
I could not find that plugin so I asked the question

Comment: Dojo has an UpgradeBar that does this: http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/branches/1.6/dojox/widget/UpgradeBar.js http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/branches/1.6/dojox/widget/UpgradeBar

Answer (score 154):

**EDIT**: The code below shows how to replicate the bars that show at the top of the screen when you get a new badge, first come to the site, etc. For the hovering dialogs that you get when you try to comment too fast, vote for your own question, etc, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758906/how-would-i-implement-stackoverflows-hovering-dialogs) where I show how to do this or  just go straight to the [example](http://jsbin.com/oqale).

---

Here's how Stackoverflow does it:

This is the markup, initially hidden so we can fade it in:

```
<div id='message' style="display: none;">
    <span>Hey, This is my Message.</span>
    <a href="#" class="close-notify">X</a>
</div>
```

Here are the styles applied:

```
#message {
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:105;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:100%;
    color:white;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color:#8E1609;
}

#message span {
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;
    float:left;
}

.close-notify {
    white-space: nowrap;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:2px #fff solid;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:3px
}

.close-notify a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

And this is javascript (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#message a.close-notify").click(function() {
        $("#message").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

And voila. Depending on your page setup you might also want to edit the body margin-top on display.

[Here is a demo of it in action.](http://jsbin.com/owuje)

Comment: Re-reading the question I don't think this is what the Op wanted. I think he's looking for the boxes that appear as notices around the site near whatever you do. I guess I'll leave this up anyways.

Comment: Paolo, Thanks for leaving this up! I think this may work quite a bit better than what I was using for this action.

Comment: While not the answer, equally helpful :P

Comment: You also need to set a cookie when you click the X so that it doesn't keep appearing as you go to more pages.

Comment: @Goat: The way I use this I only show the message once even if they don't click on the X, so I take care of it on the server-side.

Comment: I wish I could star an answer too. Thanks for this excellent entry!

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983899/does-jquery-have-a-plugin-to-display-a-message-bar-like-the-twitter-wrong-pas) is another to **show notfcation messages top of page**

Answer (score 5):

Also checkout [jQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)

Answer (score 4):

I use [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/), easy to use and you can achieve some great effects

Answer (score 4):

Using the [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) in the AJAX control toolkit is another way you can get this effect.

Comment: please comment the downvote, using a modal popup is perfectly valid for what the original question asked.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I found from viewing the StackOverflow source. Hopefully saves some time for someone. 
The showNotification function is used for all those popup messages.

```
var showNotification=function(jClicked,msg){master.showErrorPopup(jClicked.parent(),msg)};
var showFadingNotification=function(jClicked,msg){master.showErrorPopup(jClicked.parent(),msg,true)};

//master...
showErrorPopup: function (e, h, f) {
    var g = $('<div class="error-notification supernovabg"><h2>' + h + "</h2>" + (f ? "" : "(click on this box to dismiss)") + "</div>");
    var i = function () {
        g.fadeOutAndRemove()
    };
    $(e).append(g);
    g.click(i).fadeIn("fast");
    setTimeout(i, (f ? Math.max(2500, h.length * 40) : 1000 * 30))
}
```

css

```
.error-notification{z-index:1;cursor:pointer;display:none;position:absolute;padding:15px;-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #000;-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #000;box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #000;}
.error-notification a{color:inherit;text-decoration:underline;}
.error-notification li{font-size:110%;padding-top:3px;}
.supernovabg{color:#fff !important;background-color:#fe7a15 !important;}
```

It's cool how they use the length of the message to set the fading timeout. I didn't realize all the (non-fading style) messages actually fade out after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Check [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). There are some pop-up effects, modals, transitions, alerts, everything based on `javascript` and `css`.