# How to show popup message from server side

Tags: asp.net, jquery

work on asp.net vs05. i know how to show popup ,in my below syntax i show a popup when a page is load.But i want to show this popup after some action occur on server ,i have a button ,under this button event i want to do some work on server side ,then i want to show popup message .Here is my complete syntax that can show popup

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

       <script type = "text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#message a.close-notify").click(function() {
        $("#message").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div id='message' style="display: none;">
    <span>Hey, This is my Message.</span>
    <a href="#" class="close-notify">X</a>
</div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Like the above syntax i want to show popup message from server side after some event occur .Here is my aspx  syntax:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

     <script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

       <script type = "text/javascript">
    function computeCorrectValue(type parameter)
    {

            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#message a.close-notify").click(function() {
                $("#message").fadeOut("slow");
                return false;
            });
        });


    }    
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# syntax :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //want to do some work then want 


        Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:computeCorrectValue(parameter)");
    }
}
```

Help me to show popup message after some event occur on server side.popup must look like my give first example .i can show alert message too  ,but i don't want to show alert message.url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow` i want same thing but want to show after server event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a low-tech solution that keeps the script in your page template, you could add this to your HTML (this could go in `$(document).ready()` instead):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var missingInfo = '<%= this.MissingInfo %>' == 'True';
if (missingInfo) {
    alert('Not enough information. Please try again.');
}

</script>
```

And add a protected property to your Page:

```
private bool missingInfo = false;

protected bool MissingInfo {
    get { return this.missingInfo; }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    {
    // Button1 stuff ...
    // ... then if you want to show the alert
    this.missingInfo = true;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
            this, 
            this.GetType(), 
            "popup", 
            "alert('hello');", 
            true);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string script = string.Format("alert('this is alert');");
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "redirect", script, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the example code in the other answers are using alert, that is just an example.  Put your function in place of alert and you will have your popup.

Here is Darin's code with your function call:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
        this,
        this.GetType(),
        "popup",
        "computeCorrectValue(parameter);",
        true);
}
```

Though I'm really not sure where you are getting the parameter that is passed into your function.