# How to recreate Stack Overflow's welcome bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Stack Overflow has a horizontal welcome bar at the top.  Can anyone suggest how can I implement a similar bar on my website?  Is there JavaScript that defines this function?  I'm not technical but learning.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow/659243#659243

Answer (score 3):

use jquery. use jquery. use jquery.

for demo see

http://jsfiddle.net/uFhqt/4

Answer (score 0):

Dojo has an UpgradeBar that dopes this:

http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/branches/1.6/dojox/widget/UpgradeBar.js

http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/browser/branches/1.6/dojox/widget/UpgradeBar

Comment: It dopes it really really well. Dope even