# How to show pop-up message dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I create a popup based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow)
but i want to create it based on visitor

I use below code in index.aspx page:

```
<div id='message' style="display: none;">
    <span>Wellcome 
        <%=UserName%></span> <a href="#" class="close-notify" onclick="closeNotice()">X</a>
</div>
```

and I show pop-up using jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").fadeIn("slow");

});

function closeNotice() {
    $("#message").fadeOut("slow");
}
</script>
```

now i want show this pop up only when user enter OR when CheckBox1.Checked value in "editor.aspx" is true...but time pop-up display every time that page load(even if user don't log in )

Comment: Because you are firing the fade in at load (document ready).  What you need to do is have document ready call the "pop-up" on event firing.   Figure out what actions you want to cause the pop-up to load and add the message fade in/out to an .OnClick  event in the document ready function.

Comment: complete senario is based on stackoverflow pop-up...when user have new message pop-up show...when website administrator send message to user pop-up show.....also i say example in my question:is say "when CheckBox1.Checked value in "editor.aspx" is true(editor.aspx is website administrator page) pop-up must show in index.aspx...

Comment: If I understand the comment it still doesn't change things.  you want to fire the check on page load (document ready) but you don't want to fire the action to show the div unless there is something to show or on a click event.  The way you have it you will show the message div every time whether there is something to show or not.

Comment: Wrap your javascript above & possibly the message div as well in a check. Checkbox1 saves it's state somewhere, so if that state is true, then include the code, otherwise exclude it

Comment: @ somon: i use AS.NET and its compenent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a Javascript variable and set it's value on !IsPostBack.

<script  type="text/javascript">

var postBack = <%=IsPostedBack%>// you can use a variable from codebehind

if(postBack == false)
    $("#message").fadeIn("slow");

$("#message").fadeOut("slow");

</script>

Inside Page_Load function set IsPostedBack.

Comment: what happened if page is not post back but user have message??do you read my question??

Comment: How is it possible we are using variable "IsPostedBack" which is set in Page_Load function. How are you maintaining CheckBox1 value in "editor.aspx" for Index.aspx? Must be using session right then use that value for the condition as well.

Comment: Based on wikipedia "the contents of the form are **POSTed back** to the same URL as the form"...now is it postback if user load page for first time?