# writing a jquery Alert like Stackoverflow and join it to server-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, alert, stack-overflow

A asked this question few days ago but could not find my answer.

[Alert box like stackoverflow dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675704/alert-box-like-stackoverflow-dynamic-data)

I am surfing on internet for few days with no good. Some of them are usefull but message is appearing when the page loads.

**What i want is when a user fires an event all the messages should appear on top of page like this**

[image]

For this I tried this answer [Call jquery from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178881/1707848)
but the result was not i want.
Is their any other way?

Stackoverflow uses almost the same. When an answer is submited message appears at top of the window.

**Note:** Using ASP.Net WebForms.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Showing the code you used for this would help. I guess you are showing the message on a wrong event.

Comment: you can use toastr  http://codeseven.github.com/toastr/

Comment: @Ravi How to call toastr in c#. i tried using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to integrate notifications, try some jquery plugins which makes task easy with cool UI.

1. [jbar](http://tympanus.net/Development/jbar/)
2. [pnotify](http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/)
3. [toastr](http://codeseven.github.com/toastr/) (as comment added below by Ravi)

you can use ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to call javascript function as well.

Comment: add this into you're answer  http://codeseven.github.com/toastr/

Comment: @Ravi: as usual great one. Thanks.

Comment: How to call toastr in c#. i tried using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript but it is not working.

Comment: Ok i got it working. Thanks man'