# How would I implement stackoverflow's hovering dialogs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, popup

I am in ***love*** with stackoverflow's single-color "click-to-close' hovering dialog boxes that greet a user when they try to vote and aren't logged in or use the site incorrectly.  Any idea how and/or what technology Jeff used to implement these neat little devices?

**EDIT:  I'm specifically talking about the SQUARE dialog boxes that say "Click To Close" on them.  I know how to implement the rectangular strip on the top of the screen.**

Comment: look at the source code? they don't seem too complicated

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding the actual code for the dialog boxes I'm referring to, could you post the code?

Comment: SO's JavaScript is all minimized, so it'd take some effort just to decode the original source anyways.

Comment: Reading the source is tough with all the minification, but you can get some clues. For example, the flag link for your question is an anchor with id "flag-post-758906". I suggest searching question.min.js for the string "flag-post" and seeing what you'll find (as I don't have room in this comment)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604577/how-to-display-a-message-on-screen-without-refreshing-like-so-does

Comment: Hey Paolo.  I wasn't asking about the messages that get shown on the top of the screen.  I know how to do that.  I was asking about the messages that appear when a user tries to vote and is not logged in, etc.

Comment: you can un-minify the script by using this tool http://elfz.laacz.lv/beautify/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Although I was under the impression they used jQuery's UI Dialog for this, I am not too sure anymore. However, it is not too difficult to whip this up yourself. Try this code:

```
$('.showme').click(function() {
    $('.error-notification').remove();
    var $err = $('<div>').addClass('error-notification')
                         .html('<h2>Paolo is awesome</h2>(click on this box to close)')
                         .css('left', $(this).position().left);
    $(this).after($err);
    $err.fadeIn('fast');
});
$('.error-notification').live('click', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

With these styles:

```
.error-notification {
    background-color:#AE0000;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: none;
    padding:15px;
    padding-top: 0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.error-notification h2 {
    font-family:Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:140%;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}
```

And [click here](http://jsbin.com/oqale) to see it in action.

However, I think you'd still need to tweak it a little bit to give it the right positions depending on the situation in which you are using it. I took care of this for the left position because it is working for the top, but I think there may be some situations in which it won't. All things considered, this should get you started. If you want a more robust implementation, you should check out [jQuery BeautyTips](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) which is *really* awesome and would make this trivial to implement.

Comment: I've found it useful to set the z-index to something huge to bring the shown dialog to the front.

Comment: [jQuery BeautyTips](https://assets.lullabot.com/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library in conjunction with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to create [dialogs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

Comment: If you haven't checked out JQuery yet, it is so good, MS may use it instead of fixing Microsoft Ajax LOL. MS Ajax has three ways of working: Declaratively (aspx), JavaScript, and in XMLscript. Ajax 4 should have a Client Side ListView Javascript function with {data tag} replacement like a repeater.