# JQuery form validation

Tags: jquery

well my problem is that, i have a form, which i want to validate the fields using jquery, if the data is correct i let the submit continue, if no i disable the default behavior by returning false(saw that in a tutorial, [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-day-13/)).
so i used as i said the jquery syntax, when the document is ready, i registered for the click event of the button, the problme is that code never gets executed. i used firebug but no clue. nothing happens, so here is my code:

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function()
{
    var password1 = $('#form_password').val();
    var password2 = $('#form_password2').val();
    if( password1 != password2)
    {
        alert("the two passwords are not equal.");
    }
    return false; //to disable the default behavior of the submit btn
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way of checking a form submission is to check the form's `submit` event, not the button's `click` event. Change that around and what you have should work, although as it is right now it is always doing `return false;` so the form would never be sent. This should do it:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
        var motPasse1 = $('#form_motPasse').val();
        var motPasse2 = $('#form_motPasse2').val();
        if(motPasse1 != motPasse2){
            alert("Les deux mot de passe ne sont pas identiques");
            return false; // cancel form submission if passwords don't match
        }
        return true; // return true if no errors
});
```

Finally, I hope you are not keeping the `alert` there for production purposes. :) There are much, much better ways to display user notifications than an alert. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770038/best-ways-to-display-notifications-with-jquery/770059) for some suggestions, although something as simply as having an error `<div>` and fading it in is nicer than the ugly default browser alert box.

Comment: thanks but the problem, is that the form is sent every time i try. believe me, i wouldn't be asking for help if it's not the case.

Comment: Did you already try binding it to the form's submit event? As I said, if you bind it to the button's click event it is not a reliable way to check it, as pressing enter will not fire the event.

Comment: using the submit event of the form, it works fine, thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you are using a form, you could bind to the form's [`submit`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit) event:

```
$('form#id').submit(function(){
  // your validation code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation).  It's maintained by one of the members of JQuery team and it helps simplify client side form validation.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are always returning false it should look as follows:

```
$('#envoyerButton').click(function()
{
        var motPasse1 = $('#form_motPasse').val();
        var motPasse2 = $('#form_motPasse2').val();
        if( motPasse1 != motPasse2)
        {
                alert("Les deux mot de passe ne sont pas identiques");
                return false;
        }
        return true;
});
```