# How to position CSS fixed JQuery dropdown bar

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I was looking for a JQuery dropdown bar (like the one in StackOverflow) when I'll find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983899/does-jquery-have-a-plugin-to-display-a-message-bar-like-the-twitter-wrong-pass) that pointed to this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qezPE/2/). This is perfect except for one problem: when the page has scroll, it's possible that the user can't see the message.

I though that a simple "fixed" in the CSS will make the magic ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/JpLaE/)), but then a new problem appeared: the bar is not complete and centered. Now I'm blocked. What I need is the complete bar like in the first demo, but showed always even if page has scroll like in the second demo. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS declaration:

```
top: 0; 
left: 0;
width: 100%;
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/JpLaE/1/)

Comment: Great! Just a question: why "top" & "left"? It works perfect without top and left (at least in Firefox :)

Comment: Not in Chrome! :) Setting `top` and `left` to `0` ensures that the element will always be positioned at the upper-left corner. If you've got Chrome, give that demo a go and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You need 3 more css styles:

```
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
```