# How to show popup message like in Stackoverflow

Tags: jquery, popup

**Exact Duplicate: [How to show popup message like in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow)**

or

**[How would I implement stackoverflow's hovering dialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758906/how-would-i-implement-stackoverflows-hovering-dialogs)**

[alt box http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/8226/boxt.jpg](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/8226/boxt.jpg)

I am trying to build this type of information box when user click on some link with the help of jquery. 
Please help.

Comment: Just search Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758906/how-would-i-implement-stackoverflows-hovering-dialogs

Comment: Interestingly you took the screenshot while trying to down vote :)

Answer (score 6):

jQuery UI's [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) might be what you're after.