# how to create a box similar to stackoverflow, click to dismiss

Tags: jquery, dialog

**Duplicate: [How would I implement StackOverflow's hovering dialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758906/how-would-i-implement-stackoverflows-hovering-dialogs)**

---

I'm trying to create an error message, that is being displayed, so far here's a crude attempt, the message displays fine, however the click doesn't work..

```
function message(somemessage){
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('<div class="error">' + somemessage+ '</div>')
           .insertAfter( $('#ErrorMessage') ).fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).click(function(){$(this).remove});
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it because you forgot to add parenthesis after the `remove` function?

Try this

```
$('<div class="error">' + "somemessage"+ '</div>')
           .insertAfter( $('#ErrorMessage') ).fadeIn('slow').
animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).click(function(){$(this).remove()});
```

Answer (score 10):

I've already answered how to do this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758906/how-would-i-implement-stackoverflows-hovering-dialogs).

If you want, just skip straight to the [example.](http://jsbin.com/oqale)

However, if you want something more robust, you should check out the many solutions out there:

- [jQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)
- [jGrowl](http://www.stanlemon.net/projects/jgrowl.html)
- [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)
- [BeautyTips](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html)

If you wanted to see how to do the other notifications used in this website (the ones at the top when you earn a new badge, etc) you can check out how to do that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199/how-to-show-popup-message-like-in-stackoverflow).