# how i can make jquery top box like stackoverflow.com

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How would I implement stackoverflow’s hovering dialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758906/how-would-i-implement-stackoverflows-hovering-dialogs)
>   [i want a small box like stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889403/i-want-a-small-box-like-stackoverflow)

did you see the box in the top is each page 
i want do one
how

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889403/i-want-a-small-box-like-stackoverflow-closed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659199.

Comment: @Tim: well the question is "did you see the box in the top is[sic] each page".. the correct answer would probably be "yes, I have"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are doing 2 things:

1) They have a background image which is why the little magnifying glass appears:

```
#hsearch .textbox {
    background:url("http://sstatic.net/so/Img/search.png") no-repeat scroll left center #FFFFFF;
    border-color:#CCCCCC -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color #CCCCCC;
    border-right:medium none;
    border-style:solid none none solid;
    border-width:1px medium medium 1px;
    margin:0;
    max-width:230px;
    padding-left:16px;
}
```

2) When you click on the box, if the content says "search", then it's blanked out. This is done by simple javascript:

```
<input name="q" class="textbox" tabindex="1" 
    onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" 
    type="text" maxlength="80" size="28" value="search">
```

Comment: i dont mean that i mean the box that the new meaages appear in it

Comment: @oustafa - Sorry, it wasn't clear. I thought you were referring to the search box.

Comment: Wait...you don't mean the search box but you accepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like on the front page of [this site](http://my.ljvalentine.com/) ?

(It'd be a lot more helpful if you were specific.)

In my case I used [the activebar plugin](http://westhoffswelt.de/projects/activebar2.html)